# How to stop people tracking my views on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

In LinkedIn, whenever you visit a profile, that person will know that you have viewed their profile.

Is there a "settings" page for us to disable this tracking feature?

Answer (score 4):

Click your picture in the upper right corner of the main page and select "Privacy and Settings" from the drop down menu.

You'll see the following section towards the bottom of the screen:

[image]

Select the "Profile" tab, and click on "Select what others see when you've viewed their profile".  You can choose from: a) your full name, headline, and location, b) an anonymous listing with your industry and location, or c) be completely anonymous.

Comment: @jonsca, If you select anonymous, it says "selecting this option will disable *profile stats*". What does it mean?

Comment: @Pacerier It seems as though it no longer tracks views to *your* profile if you elect to be anonymous to others, that's my reading of it anyway.

Comment: @jonsca, Hmm that's weird, so we can't stay anonymous yet be able to see people who view your profile?

Comment: @Pacerier It does seem strange to me, too, but when I click the link they display in the dialog box for that setting, it brings me to people that have viewed my profile.

Comment: @jonsca, buggy Linkedin